# How to convert from .mesh format to .nodes, .ele and .face format?

Tags: mesh, tetgen

I have a 3d mesh in .mesh format which can be read by medit visualization program.
However I need to convert it into the .nodes, .ele and .face format that is the output format of tetgen (the 3d Delaunay tetrahedralization program) . What is the best way to do this conversion of formats? Is there a free program available to do this conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MEDIT_TO_FEM program](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/cpp_src/medit_to_fem/medit_to_fem.html) produces .node and .ele files from an medit .mesh file.

You might have to hack it to get triangles, though. It's simple: each (positively-oriented) tetrahedral element with vertices

> v0 v1 v2 v3

has triangular faces

> v0 v1 v2
>
> v1 v3 v2
>
> v2 v3 v0
>
> v3 v1 v2

The orientation of the faces will of course depend on the orientation of the element, so your triangles might require a different ordering of their vertices.